# How to add ~/bin/directory to a mac?

Tags: macos

Sorry if this may be a stupid or simple question, but I am trying to install a program to my "bin" directory on my mac. Here is what it says:

Download a copy of changeInput by _________ and save it to the ~/bin/directory. > Note: You may need to create the ~/bin/ directory if it doesn’t already exist.

I seem to have "~bin" but I do not have the directory. I also cannot paste anything to this directory.

Once again, this may be a simple question for you, but please let me know how to do this on a mac(OS X). Thanks!

Comment: Open a terminal then `cd ~; mkdir bin`

Comment: On macOS, I'd recommend using ~/Library/bin instead of ~/bin; ~/Library is a hidden folder that contains files that're used automatically, and a binaries directory (that's in your PATH) fits into this category. To create it, use `mkdir ~/Library/bin`. Then use `~/Library/bin` wherever the instructions say to use `~/bin`.